# Directus GET users/me? with 404 response

Tags: php, api, curl, request, directus

I try to authenticate myself on directus (version 7) backend on `/directus/public/admin/`.
Then try to collect the userdata and collections (the tables) ends in a 404

```
directus/public/_/users/me?fields%5B0%5D=id&fields%5B1%5D=avatar.%2A&fields%5B2%5D=email&fields%5B3%5D=first_name&fields%5B4%5D=last_name&fields%5B5%5D=locale&fields%5B6%5D=roles.%2A.%2A
```

The ping to the API after that is with a 200 okay and it shows the API is reachable.

```
/directus/public/server/ping
```

[image: image shows the network thread]

Anyone here with an idea ? I stand here for more information if needed.

Comment: Are you authenticated when using the `/users/me` endpoint? How are you passing the token?

Comment: i use "Postman" for my tests.
For auth i use 
/directus/public/_/auth/authenticate
and get a token.
After that i try 
/directus/public/_/users/me
and get a code 203.
The token is delivered by Authorization (Basic Auth) in the "Username" Field.
This project runs on other space without problems.

Comment: Rijk ? Anyone with a idea here please ?

Comment: Same issue here, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Hi Ernie, not yet. Thought i get some answers from Rijk.